# AngularJS Normal Binding vs One Time Binding With Rerendering Element

Tags: angularjs

In my angular projects, I prefer to use one-way-binding for performance like this

```
<div>
    <p ng-bind="::vm.user.name"></p>
    <p ng-bind="::vm.user.email"></p>    
    <!-- other bindings -->
</div>
```

But when the view items changes, the DOM must be rerendered for displaying new values. So I use ng-if for this. So it looks like

```
<div ng-if="vm.user">
    <p ng-bind="::vm.user.name"></p>
    <p ng-bind="::vm.user.email"></p>
    <!-- other bindings -->    
</div>
```

And for rerendering the DOM, I use a function

```
function updateUser(user){
    vm.user = null;
    $timeout(function(){
        vm.user = user;
    });
}
```

This rendering method works but there is a rendering cost on each item updates. Other way is using two-way-bindings without ng-if but this kind of bindings create watchers and it causes performance problems.

```
<div>
    <p ng-bind="vm.user.name"></p>
    <p ng-bind="vm.user.email"></p>    
    <!-- other bindings -->
</div>
```

I cannot make a desicion between two approaches. Which one is the good for best performence? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if your model will not change use One way data binding, Otherwise prefer to use two way data binding for consistency and simplicity. Since ngIf directive is also uses $scope.watch so it is also performance decreasing

Comment: What if count of inner ng-bind is more than 10?